# Picture won't display with ImageView

Tags: javafx, imageview

I am attempting to complete a homework assignment which requires us to use pictures stored in a common folder on the school server. I successfully got the assignment to work on my laptop(Mac) by downloading the folder and copying it to to my bin folder, however this method won't work for submission since all we do is upload the .java file for grading. My problem is getting the image to load using a file pathway to somewhere on the network. To try to test this method I've created a dummy program in which I try to display a file from a folder on my desktop. Still no dice. I am relatively new to javafx, but from what I've read, the code I've been attempting should be working, but isn't.

Originally I didn't need to use an Image object to work with ImageView, but the internet seems to think I need to. I'm not sure what do do. My main real question is, how many levels of folders do I have to include after the "file:..." part of the string? I assume that, since I have no idea what computer my professor uses to run our programs, I would need to go all the way up to the name of the drive in which the folder of pictures is stored(in this case, U:). Also, how can I get it to work from my desktop? Since the dummy program is on the same drive as the picture folder, will the "level" of folders be different?

PS:
My program works with a String array of filenames being generated using a for loop. The file names wind up being something like, "incorrect_folder\this_is_annoying\Cards\"+a+".png".
This method posed no problems before when the folder was in my bin, but I thought I'd mention it to cover all my bases.

I'm really starting to run out of time on this project, and this one little snag is really frustrating. Please help.

Comment: Surely the assignment specifies the file location of the image? Is there another way (e.g. http) you can access it?

Comment: I have recently had some success with my dummy program with: Image image = new Image("file:/Users/my_username/Desktop/Cards/1.png");

Comment: He said this in an email:  Try something like this: "file:///Y:/CSC Courses/CSC164/Lu/book/image/card/" I don't know why he used the Y drive instead of U, which was where they were located, or why he used used three slashes

Comment: @James_D: The folder is on a server at my school, and I don't know how I would access it from home. All he said in the assignment was that it was on the U: drive. My real question is, how "deep" do I have to go in order for it to work since the folder is in a different drive than the .java file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't possibly access it as a relative path, since you have no idea what the working directory is. You need to access it as an absolute path, sort of as he describes in the email snippet you provide in the comments. There's still a problem though as you have no idea what drive letter he would choose to map the drive (the user can basically choose any drive letter they want for a mapped network drive).

I would also recommend creating the `File` object first and then creating a URL from it, instead of hardcoding the URL scheme (`file://`). I would also check the folder exists, using your best guess, and then give the user the chance to choose a folder if it doesn't (using a [`DirectoryChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html)). So in partial pseudocode:

```
File folder = new File("Y:/CSC Courses/CSC164/Lu/book/image/card");
if (! folder.exists()) {
    // use DirectoryChooser to let user chooser directory with images...
}
File imageFile = new File(folder, "1.png");
try {
    Image image = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
    // do whatever you need with image...
} catch (MalformedURLException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: So catch the exception if it occurs (which is should not, in this context).

Comment: I don't understand. I deleted the comment to try to format it better but you were wicked fast!

Comment: disregard previous comment, initializing the image to null fixed the issue!